# how can i solve " NoneType Error" in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, nonetype

I am trying to use OpenCV in python I got this error " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'" when I run

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("C:\python\Scripts\bratislava_castle.jpg")
print(image.shape)
```

[image]

I have added the path from the environment settings but still i have this error shows up

Comment: Use a raw string: `cv2.imread(r"C:\python\Scripts\bratislava_castle.jpg")`

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `\` with `\\` in your path:

```
cv2.imread( "C:\\python\\Scripts\\bratislava_castle.jpg")
```

Otherwise you don't read the file properly, and your `image` is `None`.

Comment: thank you for helping i did the \\ but sill same error and my path is correct

Comment: On your screenshot only a handful of files have extension, for example, your python script is just `test1`, while actually it is `test1.py` -- please, turn on display of file extensions and make sure your image file does not have an extra extension, like `bratislava_castle.jpg.png` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in your variable `iamge`. Your `imread()` method probably returns `None`.

Make sure that's the correct absolute path and if it's try using a raw string, e.g.

> cv2.imread(r"C:\python\Scripts\bratislava_castle.jpg")

Comment: thanks for your help  i added the correct path i still have the error

Comment: Weird. can you try a relative path like this `cv2.imread("..\Scripts\bratislava_castle.jpg")` and see if it works. can you also try the `png` image and see if that works?